# How to use and enable sentiment analysis in azure bot framework

Tags: azure, botframework, sentiment-analysis

How to use and enable sentiment analysis in azure bot framework,
i want to implement sentimental analysis using azure bot framework.

Comment: You have to call `azure sentiment analysis endpoint API` from your bot. You can found more details on this [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/sentiment-opinion-mining/quickstart?pivots=programming-language-csharp)

Answer (score 0):

As [Md Farid Uddin Kiron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9663070/md-farid-uddin-kiron) said, you can use
`azure sentiment analysis endpoint API`

same can be implemented by referring https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/sentiment-opinion-mining/quickstart?pivots=programming-language-csharp#setting-up